# Freestyle rendering out of sync with pose 2.8

Tags: rendering, freestyle

I am running into this issue where the Freestyle outline that is rendered is not in sync with the pose of the character being rendered.

[image]

Things that I've tried:

- Applying the Armature's transforms to be zeroed on the mesh
- Applying the Mesh's transforms to be zeroed on the origin as well
- Freestyle's settings are default and haven't really been touched
- Re-Applying the rest pose
- disabled the pose library

It appears the pose is getting multiplied, but I have no idea why, and why it is different than what is rendered solid.

What else should I check?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was using a slightly older (by about a month) version of 2.8.  Updating to the latest version fixed my issue.